# Browser crashing from too many audio files?

Tags: jquery, html

I created a website which has about 35 audio files that get played with different keydown events in jQuery. I haven't launched the site yet, but am having problems with the browser crashing when I open it from my computer. The files are embedded in my html using the audio tag as both mp3 and ogg files.

Is there a general rule of thumb for not having too many audio or visual elements on a web page? Do I just have to wait for all of them to load before actually running the keydown events?

I am on a mac and using Safari.

Thanks for your help!
Paul

Comment: How big are the mp3 files?

Comment: @putvande its not the size that matters, its how you use it.

Comment: I think it does matter how big they are, if they get loaded in the browser it can crash under the enormous size of the mp3s

Comment: @PedroEstrada: I see what you did there.

Comment: A lot is going to depend on the browser type and, the specifications of the computer that the user is on. e.g. My machine freezes for about 30secs when I try to open a 'mashable' page !

Comment: The mp3s are about 20KB each, and I also have ogg files attached as well that are about 25KB each. So, as a conservative estimate, 30 * 45 = 1350 KB. Is this too much?